# What scopes do names in function parameters belong to?

Tags: python, function, scope, parameter-passing, stack-memory

```
def a(l=[]):
    print(l)
    l.append('something')

a()     #[]
a()     # ['something']
```

after `a` is executed for the first time
it seems to be that `a`'s parameter name `l` and the actual object in heap memory attached to it should be erased from memory
because there is nothing in stack memory that refers l 's object in heap memory
`a` is executed so l 's local scope doesn't exist any more and so name l doesn't exist anymore => l cannot refer anything anymore

but empirically I have found that it does not work this way
if we write `a` like this `def a(l=[]):` and then call it like this `a()`
it seems to be that name 'l' continues to exist even after `a` is already executed
I mean that the object in heap bind to name `l` continues to exists and stores all alterations caused to it by the first call of `a`

and when we call `a` for the second time
its first line `print(l)` prints not empty [] but ['something']
so it seems to be like by the first calling of `a` we change the `a`'s' code itself
from this:

```
def a(l=[]):
print(l)
l.append('something')
```

to this

```
def a(l=['something']):
print(l)
l.append('something')
```

I thought that if I write a function like this `def a(l=[]):`
every next time I call it like this `a()`
its name parameter written like that `foo(name_parameter=[]`
will be rewritten (or newly created in new 'clear', 'empty' scope)
but that's not the case as we can see

my question:
how it works?
what mechanics is lied behind it?

why in the time when `a` is not executing and so its entrails names should not exist in memory
`a`'s parameters assigned `a(HERE)` (and not reassigned anywhere else later) nevertheless exist in memory?

Comment: See ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).

Comment: you could confirm the prevalence of same object l by printing id(l) in the function. The address may remain the same.

Comment: @user2685079 I know it. And craighb's link explains the problem in full. The explanation was easy to get if we look at this in OOP paradigm: any function is object, and when we call `def a(l=[]):` for the first time data attribute `l` is set to object `a` but when we call it for the subsequent times object `a` already has data attribute `l` so this part `l=[]` of `def a(l=[]):` won't be executed because it's to be executed only of there is no `l` name in `a`'s namespace, but there already is. It has nothing to do with stack names and scopes it's about understanding OOP only.